# Vuejs eventbus triggers multiple times due to webpack import outport?

Tags: javascript, events, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

In a vuejs project I use the vue eventbus like [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/). Emitting this event:

```
  icontag.addEventListener('click', testFunction, false)

  function testFunction () {
    console.log('click1')
    Events.$emit('click2')
  }
```

And receiving it in another module I get as output one click1, but multiple click2's. It looks very much like every time there is some code which requires webpack import/ export it triggers an additional result on the eventbus of the same event..., or something..., since in chrome devtools the related code close to the click2's has code like `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__util` nearby.

Any idea what is going on?

EDIT:
I think it might have been a 'corrupted hot-reload setup'. After rebuilding the dev hot-reload build, the issue seems gone now. Still interested in similar experiences as the issue was pretty ugly and persistent.

Comment: Probably more likely that the code never *removes* the handler. If a component that adds a handler is created/mounted multiple times without removing the handler, then you will get this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comment from Bert is right. You can actually register many times the same eventhandlers on the same event.

Try removing the eventhandler before adding it again.

```
icontag.removeEventListener("click", testFunction);
icontag.addEventListener('click', testFunction, false)

function testFunction () {
  console.log('click1')
  Events.$emit('click2')
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this must have been it as the amount of events only increased (now and then), so then it must have registered again somehow etc.